# Changing dynamincally value of other elements

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'd like to ask how could I change dynamically the value of a table based on the option from the select menu that the user has chosen.
**I'm using mongoDB and those values like "difficulty" are already saved in the database(screenshot).**

I have this problem because I can't put a js variable into my EJS template so I can't tell which robbery is selected.

Like in this screenshot: 
[Image of my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyV35.png)

This is my EJS part of the page

```
<form class="robbery-form">
    <select>
        <% if(typeof robbery !== 'undefined') {%>
            <% for(var i=0; i<robbery.length; i++) {%>
                <option><%= robbery[i].name %></option>
            <% } %>
        <% } %>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Do it!">
</form>
```